# Woocommerce - Change order received text after redirecting from PayPal with IPN

Tags: redirect, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I like to change the thank you page text in case the customer already paid via paypal.
Redirecting via PayPal works fine. Order status is "processing", ok.
But how can I change the thank you text on the redirecting page (https://www.example.com/checkout/order-received/)

I tried the following, with no success:

```
function my_update_order_status() {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    if ($order_status == 'processing')
        echo 'NEW MESSAGE';
    else
        echo 'NOT PAID TEXT';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'my_update_order_status', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation on how to change the thank you page here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-edit-the-thank-youorder-received-page

If you don't wish to do any template modifying then you can include the order received function to adjust it. For example:

```
function isa_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
    $new = $text . ' All received and an email is on its way to you!.';
    return $new;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'isa_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
```

The above with add text to the current text output.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to do it with a hook and a function in my function.php without editing a template. Isn't there a solution similiar to the example above?

Comment: Nobody? Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry I never saw your response. The above is to be used in a functions.php file within the template. OR you can write your own plugin to intercept it.